# Swift Generate Odd Array Issue

Tags: swift

We given a task to create a swift function to generate and return an array of an odd number for a given number of element.

If element is generate(5) then output will be [1,3,5,7,9]

For above task we had return below code which is not working -

```
import Foundation
func generate(len: Int) -> [Int] {
    let count = len.count - 1
    var oddArray = [Int]()
    for i in 0 ... count{
        let val = len[i] % 2 
        if val != 0 {
            oddArray.append(len[i])
        }
    }
    return Array[oddArray]
}
let stdout = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: stdout, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: stdout)!
guard let len = Int((readLine()?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))!)
else { fatalError("Bad input") }
let result = generate(len: len)
fileHandle.write(result.map{ String($0) }.joined(separator: "\n").data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

We are getting error as -

**solution.swift:5:17: error: value of type 'Int' has no member 'count'
let count = len.count - 1**

**solution.swift:13:12: error: instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'Array<_>'
return Array[oddArray]**

Comment: Why should `generate(7)` return `[1,3,5,7,9]`? Shouldn't it be `[1,3,5,7,9,11,13]` (7 elements)?

Comment: correct it should be [1,3,5,7,9,11,13] only :-)

Comment: `var oddArray: [Int] = []` `for value in 1 ..< len*2 where !value.isMultiple(of: 2) {` `oddArray.append(value)` `}` `return oddArray`

Comment: Just fixing your code should look like this: `func generate(len: Int) -> [Int] {` `var oddArray = [Int]()` `for i in 1 ..< len*2 {` `let val = i % 2` `if val != 0 {` `oddArray.append(i)` `}` `}` `return oddArray` `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stride(from:to:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride) to create a sequence of odd numbers and `Array()` to turn that into the array:

```
func generate(len: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard len > 0 else { return [] }
    return Array(stride(from: 1, to: len * 2, by: 2))
}
```

**Examples:**

```
print(generate(len: 4))
```

> ```
> [1, 3, 5, 7]
> ```

```
print(generate(len: 7))
```

> ```
> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
> ```

Comment: can u please tell anything wrong in

```
func removeDuplicate(inputArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {
var set = Set()
var result = Array()
for number in inputArray {
if set.contains(number) {
continue
}
set.insert(number)
result.append(number)
}
return result
}
```